# this in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the snippet in Javascript,

```
        var objt = {

            fn :    function(three, four){
                    four();             //    window as (this === window)
                }
        }       


        objt.fn(3, function(){
            alert(this);         //    window as (this === window)

        });
```

The above is ***not a constructor function***. Inside a function, the value of ***this*** depends ***on how the function is called***. The function

```
            function(){
                alert(this);                    
            }
```

was passed as an argument and as such ***wasn't linked to the objt***. No issues with ***this***.

Now consider the snippet in AngularJS regarding module and controller,

```
myModule.controller('MainCtrl', function(x1, x2) {
    var main = this;

    alert(this === window);  // alert false, why and what is this here?

});
```

Comment: It could be the controller itself or the $scope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `this` is a tricky one and internally depends on the scope you are in. If you declare function in global scope, `this` will be equal to the `window` since `window` is the global scope.

However since you are inside controller scope in Angular, `this` no longer refers to the `window` object, thus it becomes your controller object.

Comment: Also suggest to read [scope vs. context](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

Comment: Also note that `this` can be changed to anything via `Function.prototype.call()` (or others).

Comment: Thank you evc and Rouby and indeed Kamo for helping me out.